# GitHub PR squash causes erroneous merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm wondering if this is a GitHub bug and wanted see if anyone else has seen this issue.
I have `master`, `dev`, and `feature` branches in my GitHub repo.

Process usually looks like this:

```
master : A
dev    : A 
feature: A - B - C
```

Then I merge `feature` into `dev` and delete `feature` branch, but I don't squash to keep all the commit history:

```
master : A
dev    : A - B - C
```

When I merge into `master`, I squash the merge to make it seem cleaner:

```
master : A - BC
               \
dev    : A - B - C
```

I understand that `BC` is more like a separate commit at this point, but `master` code at `BC` and `dev` code at `C` are identical.

I'm noting a weird issue when I compare between `master` and `dev` at the stage above; I see a lot of conflicts when I try to merge `dev` into `master` again or vice versa.

The conflict doesn't change whether I'm merging `dev` into `master` or `master` into `dev`; for example, if `dev -> master` code difference is `-a and +b`, I'd see the same difference when I try to merge `master -> dev`, not `-b and +a`.

We want to continue to build features on top of `dev` branch and keep its history, so deleting it and creating a new branch based on `master` wouldn't be an option.

I'm using GitHub to squash & merge as other members need to approve the changes before I can merge into `master`.

Could anyone explain why I am seeing this issue and how to work around it?

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This drawing:

```
master : A - BC
               \
dev    : A - B - C
```

implies there's some sort of link between `C` and `BC`.

There is no such link, but there *is* a link between `A` and `B` (specifically from `B` back to `A`).  So a more accurate drawing is:

```
A--D   <-- master
 \
  B--C   <-- dev
```

where `D` has the same *snapshot* as `C`, but is unrelated, hence the name `D`.

This is the source of the entire problem:

> I see a lot of conflicts when I try to merge `dev` into `master` again or vice versa.

As far as Git is concerned, the point at which `dev` and `master` correspond is commit `A`.  Git must therefore take the diff from `A` to `C` and apply that again to `master`, which—in Git's eyes—does not have either `B` or `C` yet.

> We want to continue to build features on top of `dev` branch and keep its history, so deleting it and creating a new branch based on `master` wouldn't be an option.

In that case, stop doing squashes, because squash effectively "kills off" a branch: you should never do anything more with the `B-C` commits.  Just do a real merge.  From the GitHub web UI, selecting "merge" will do this; from the command line, use `git merge --no-ff`.  Then instead of a new totally-independent commit `D`, you'll get a merge commit (which I'll still call `D`):

```
A------D   <-- master
 \    /
  B--C   <-- dev
```

When you do more work on `dev` you get:

```
A------D   <-- master
 \    /
  B--C--E--F   <-- dev
```

and you can now do another merge.  This time there is no need for `--no-ff`, though it will still work fine; on the GitHub web UI there's nothing to change either.  You'll get a new merge commit `G`:

```
A------D-----G   <-- master
 \    /     /
  B--C--E--F   <-- dev
```

The inputs to this second merge are commit `C` as the merge base, commit `D` as `--ours`, and commit `F` as `--theirs`, so the merge will go smoothly.  As before, the snapshots in `C` and `D` will match, and the snapshots in `F` and `G` will match.

If you want to see what happened strictly from the point of view of `master`, use:

```
git log --first-parent master
```

This directs `git log` to look only at the *first* parent of each merge commit.  That is, Git will start by showing you commit `G`, to which `master` points.  Then it will move from `G` to its first parent `D`, and show that commit.  Then it will move from `D` to its first parent `A` and show that commit.  As there are no earlier commits at all, `git log` now stops, with its job finished.

(Of course, if there are commits before `A`, `git log` will go on to show them, but all the drawings here have no commits before `A`.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Quick question, if we weren't concerned about keeping each commit history, would squashing `feature` into `dev` then simply merging `dev` into `master` help us avoid this merge conflict issue?

Comment: Or should we perform `git rebase -i` on `feature` before we merge into `dev`? We have restriction on `master` branch and it can't be merged without a peer review, so thinking about ways to avoid using CLI.

Comment: Also, from your top diagram, I get that git compares `A` to `C`, but it still feels funny. Why on earth can't git compare `D` to `C` when `A` is linked with `D` and they're using the same code base?

Comment: There are lots of possible work-flows. The one we use where I am now is pretty rebase-heavy and had become a problem, but we have recently headed off the problem by making our Jenkins tests take 2 minutes instead of 40 (using Jenkins v2 and pre-baked docker images).

Comment: To address the comparisons question, see any of my rather many articles on how Git actually performs `git merge`. Note that the key difference between `git merge --squash` and `git merge --no-ff` is that the former always makes a non-merge commit in the end, while the latter always makes a merge commit in the end—i.e., the recorded histories are different, even though the stored snapshot is the same for each kind of merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already squashed the the base branch into main/master, the solution is to interactive rebase all commits from the base branch.

Assuming this is the current state

```
master : A - BC
               \
dev    : A - B - C - D
```

Do a `rebase -i HEAD~3` on dev, squash `C` into `B`. Then, parent commit of `D` will be not same but similar to master. When you perform a `git rebase master`, you will not face a merge conflict.

**Important**
This practice rewrites git history. This means you will have to force push changes. Never do that on shared branches as it will break the git state of other users. Consider consulting [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in git-scm for more details. This practice is safe to use for Pull/Merge Requests where a single developer is working on it.